# How to stop SqlAlchemy from generating SQL that inserts or updates the primary key?

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a model:

```
class Contact(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'contact'

    contactid = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, server_default=db.text("nextval('contact_contactid_seq'::regclass)"))
    firstname = db.Column(db.Text)
    lastname = db.Column(db.Text)
```

and a form

```
class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
    contactid = HiddenField('contactid')
    firstname = StringField('First Name', validators=[Optional()], filters = [lambda x: x or None])
    lastname = StringField('Last Name', validators=[Optional()], filters = [lambda x: x or None])
    submit = SubmitField('Save')
```

I use code similar to the following to insert and update records in the database using the above model and form

```
@blueprint.route('/create', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create():
    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        r = Contact()
        form.populate_obj(r)
        db.session.add(r)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("saved new record", "success")
        return root()

    return render_template('contact/create.html', form=form)


@blueprint.route('/edit/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(id: int):
    r = Contact.query.get_or_404(id)
    form = ContactForm(obj=r)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(r)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("updated record", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('blueprint.root'))

    return render_template('contact/edit.html', form=form)
```

**The Problem**

SQLAlchemy appears to be generating SQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO contact (contactid, firstname, lastname) VALUES (%(contactid)s, %(firstname)s, %(lastname)s)

UPDATE contact set contactid=%(contactid)s, firstname=%(firstname)s, lastname=%(lastname)s WHERE contactid = %(contactid)s
```

I want it to do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO contact (firstname, lastname) VALUES (%(firstname)s, %(lastname)s)
SELECT last_contactid_somehow

UPDATE contact set firstname=%(firstname)s, lastname=%(lastname)s WHERE contactid = %(contactid)s
```

What am I doing wrong?

I would like a solution where SqlAlchemy:

- handles the auto-incrementing primary key without sticking it into the insert statement
- doesn't set the primary key in the update statement

I am using Postgres

Comment: re: insert - In `def create():`, after you call `form.populate_obj(r)` is `r.contactid` set to `None`?

Comment: It appears to be set to not None somehow, should I stop using `populate_obj`?

Comment: re: update - It is not "setting" the PK, it is using the PK in the WHERE clause to tell the database which row to update.

Comment: "[on insert] It appears to be set to not None somehow" - That explains the behaviour. You'll need to fix that. (You could just brute-force it with `r.contactid = None`. Not pretty, but it would work.)

Comment: I wonder what is coercing it to not None.  I'm guessing it's the HiddenField in the form?

Comment: Could be some leftover value from a previous invocation of the form. Just a guess.

Comment: I think it is the HiddenField -- I added another one of those lambdas that corces empty string to None and it's now set to None.

Comment: The Original Question that I asked is now answered for insert statements. It stopped trying to put the PK into the insert statement.  Thank you!  However, it still puts the PK into the update statements? (in the SET clause)  I understand it being in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first problem will be solved by setting **autoincrement=True**

```
class Contact(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'contact'

    contactid = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, server_default=db.text("nextval('contact_contactid_seq'::regclass)"))
    ...
```

the second problem is actually working properly because you defined the form class like that.

In addition, the query you want and the query generated by SQLAlchemy are the same because the contractid in the where clause and the contractid in the set clause is same.

Nevertheless, if you want to change the query, change the value of the model object.

```
r = Contact.query.get_or_404(id)
form = ContactForm(obj=r)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        r.firstname = form.firstname.data
        r.lastname = form.lastname.data
        db.session.commit()
        ...
```

Comment: Actually, `autoincrement=True` won't change the behaviour. If the PK column is writable in the database table and the ORM object has had a value assigned to the PK attribute (field) then SQLAlchemy will do its best to write that value to the table because that's what we asked it to do. If the operation ultimately causes an exception then it's up to the programmer to handle it.